# PHP - print_r(get_defined_vars()); returns blank screen

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a variable dump in my php so I'm using:

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

to produce it, but it results in a blank page no matter where I insert the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is the code being reached? i.e. If you put `print 'test';` afterwards, does it display `test`?

Answer (score 2):

One of the outputted variables may contain HTML,CSS and/or JavaScript-code that prevents the site from being loaded.

Look at the source code (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in most browsers, or right-click → `View Source`) instead of the rendered page to see everything that your php script outputs.

Also, make sure that the php code gets actually executed, by inserting an `echo "test";`. That should show up, at least in the source code.

Comment: Nope, nothing on the page renders.  Tried wrapping it in <pre> and no dice.

Comment: @JonLachonis It's not about *rendering* that's kind of the point of the answer. What URL are you looking at? It should start with `view-source:` in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Well of course your code is correct, so the reason for the blank page must be that there is some error elsewhere (does the page work if you do NOT put that line in?); maybe your line breaks the syntax of a code block.

Then the error is redirected to php_errors.log or some other file, or maybe is not even generated, and you see a blank page.

Check:

- to have error_reporting(E_ALL) in your script, at the earliest occasion
- that the errors go where they should in php.ini

  - check those error log files (if any)
- check server error logs (e.g. Apache's error_log file).

Once you've cleared the upstream error, you should be able to see your output.

Answer (score 2):

`get_defined_vars` includes `$GLOBALS` among its returned variables, and `print_r` doesn't check for recursion. Therefore you are simply winding up in an infinite loop that not even `max_execution_time` can save you from.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe If you are developing extension/plugin for a script that uses ioncube as protection, then maybe it is the issue, Ioncube seems to stop `get_defined_vars()` as a part of preventing reverse engineering.